# How do i read embedded bytarray file?

Tags: apache-flex, arrays, filereference

I created a tile map editor for my game and it will generate a file when the user is done with the design. The file will store the assets used and other information.

this is the code on how i generate the file

```
                var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                var masterData:Object = { map:Data.instance.mapLayerArr, 
                                               asset:assetCollection, 
                                               gridrow:Data.instance.gridRow,
                                               gridColumn: Data.instance.gridColumn,
                                               cellWidth: Data.instance.cellWidth,
                                               cellHeight: Data.instance.cellHeight,
                                               assetCount: Data.instance.assetCount,
                                               layerCount: Data.instance.layerCount,
                                               version: Data.instance.version};

                ba.writeObject(masterData);
                ba.compress();
                file = new FileReference();
                file.save(ba, Data.instance.fileName);
```

problem starts when i want to embed the generated file inside my game.

this is the code in my program.

```
    [Embed(source='../../../../res/tilemapdata/File Name', mimeType='application/octet-stream')]
    public static const TileMapFile:Class;

    public function TileMapLoader() 
    {
        var byteArray:ByteArray;
        byteArray = new TileMapFile();

        byteArray.uncompress();
        var obj:Object;
        obj = byteArray.readObject();
        trace(fileReference);
    }
```

whenever i run it ends in "obj = byteArray.readObject();" and will display this error.

```
[Fault] exception, information=ArgumentError: Error #2173: Unable to read object in stream.  The class flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection does not implement flash.utils.IExternalizable but is aliased to an externalizable class.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a strange class `flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection` - try replacing all such imports with `mx.collections.ArrayCollection`.

Also make sure that all classes that are stored in file has `[RemoteClass]` metatag or they would be restored as `Object` instances.

Answer (score 0):

A good read about the situation (adobe's official documentation): ([Explicitly mapping ActionScript and Java objects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/programmer/lcds/help.html?content=serialize_data_3.html))

I have experianced the same problem. General rules which help me to solve:

- better to have explicitly declared metatag [RemoteClass] on your client-side actionscript classes.
- collections of server-side classes (lists,arrays,etc.) easier to handle when represented client-side flash by mx.collections.ArrayCollection.
- at some point you may need to explicitly declare client-side Flash class with the server-side class relationship by coding before any deserialization occures `flash.net.registerClassAlias("net.acme.serverside.Foo", clientside.Foo );` otherwise your objects goes untyped as generic `flash.Object` after deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Check, that your ArrayCollection alias registered by this way:

```
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
...
registerClassAlias("flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection", ArrayCollection);
```

instead of:

```
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
...
registerClassAlias("mx.collections.ArrayCollection", ArrayCollection);
```

There explanation:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/javadoc/flex/messaging/io/ArrayCollection.html